# styling of drop down list box

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have bunch of text box and drop down list on my web page. The text box look and feel is totally different than the drop down box in my MVC view. Text box is automatically generated by CRUD operations of MVC, but I put the dropdown list on my page on my own. Below is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Office, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Office, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "Width:50%" } })




    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownList("Groups", ViewBag.Groupie as SelectList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "Width:50%" } })
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Group, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "Width:50%" } })


    </div>
```

in below image, I want the look of Dropdownlist just like textbox. same width and height. Drop down Group is way too small in front of Group text box.

[image]

Comment: not sure if this is the cause without seeing what your css is doing, but I notice the container divs of the textboxes have a class applied - `form-group`, but the dropdownlists div doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Office, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Office, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "Width:50%" } })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownList("Groups", ViewBag.Groupie as SelectList, new{ @class = "form-control", style = "Width:50%"  })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Group, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Group, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "Width:50%" } })
 </div>
```

**User this code.**